# How do i call a CGI script from PHP

Tags: php, cgi

I have tried all the suggestions i have seen on how to do this but none seem to be working. Please how do i call an external CGI script (on another website) from a PHP script and collect  the output of the script.

The URL given to me is something like this:

```
https://abc.com/cgi-bin/mbsn.cgi?
PRODUCT_ID=35277&ORDER_ID=12345&QUANTITY=1&FIRSTNAME=Sam&LASTNAME=K&E
MAIL=admin@xyz.com
```

Thanks.

Comment: http://php.net/file_get_contents

Comment: It gives me an error about it been disabled in server config

Comment: Then you need to use http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php if that's available, or speak to your hosting provider about enabling the necessary settings in the server configuration.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you want to do is get the results of a web page.  It doesn't really matter that it's cgi.

PHP has several methods for doing this.

1. `file_get_contents()` http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php
2. `curl()` http://www.php.net/manual/en/curl.examples-basic.php

Either one of these should get you what you want.